# How to access BERT's inter layer?

Tags: nlp, bert-language-model, pre-trained-model

I want to put [batch_size, 768, text_length] tensor into
6th layer of BERT.

1. How can I give input to 6th layer?
2. Can I take just 6~last layer of BERT then use it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use only the last 6 layers of BERT, you can create a new model that only consists of these layers, using the following code:

```
import torch
from transformers import BertModel

model = BertModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
last_6_layers = torch.nn.ModuleList(model.bert.encoder.layer[-6:]).to(device)
```

This will create a new model last_6_layers that consists of only the last 6 layers of the BERT model. You can then input your [batch_size, 768, text_length] tensor into this new model and use it for your specific task.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. 
Thanks to you, I was able to get the last six layers of Bert.
Could you give me some advice on how to put in the input?
--------------------------------------------
`print(y.shape) #torch.Size([16, 256, 768])
y=self.last_6_layers(y).pooler_output`
--------------------------------------------
when I do this,
I got NotImplementedError.

I'd appreciate it if you could answer.